# Proving inequalities (1)

Tags: inequality, radicals, fractions, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Let $a, b, c > 0$ $;abc=8$  ,
>   $$\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{(1+a^3)(1+b^3)}}
> + \frac{b^2}{\sqrt{(1+b^3)(1+c^3)}}
> + \frac{c^2}{\sqrt{(1+c^3)(1+a^3)}} \ge \frac43
> $$
>   (ref: [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIg8V.jpg))

I tried using AM-GM to eliminate the square root on the bottom but I am stuck, what is the general strategy here and maybe I can use its symmetry?

Comment: As you've been around awhile, perhaps you could make the attempt to [post using mathematical expressions](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) ?  Readers will help if needed.

Answer (score 1):

By AM-GM $$1+a^3=(1+a)(1-a+a^2)\leq\left(\frac{1+a+1-a+a^2}{2}\right)^2=\frac{(2+a^2)^2}{4}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{(2+a^2)(2+b^2)}\geq\frac{1}{3}$$ or 
$$3\sum_{cyc}a^2(2+c^2)\geq\prod_{cyc}(2+a^2)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^2b^2+2a^2)\geq72,$$ which is true by AM-GM:
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^2b^2+2a^2)\geq3\sqrt[3]{a^4b^4c^4}+6\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}=3\cdot16+6\cdot4=72.$$
Done!

Comment: edited already i forgot the abc=8

Comment: @SuperMage1 I also fixed my post. See now.